# Rust apply upsert on update

Tags: rust

I'm using `mongodb` and I have a function to increment a field called **"id"** by 1.

```
let mongo_colecction = conecction_bd::my_bd_collection("AutoCode").await?;
let filter = doc! {
    "collection": "Student"
};
let update = doc! {
    "$inc": { "id": 1 }
};
let option = doc! {
    "upsert": true
};
let document = mongo_colecction.find_one_and_update(filter, update, option).await;
/* 
    Here continues the code to update
*/
```

But I am getting an error and I don't know how I can fix it.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<FindOneAndUpdateOptions>: From<bson::Document>` is not satisfied
  --> src\increase_code.rs:34:47
   |
34 |         let document = mongo_colecction.find_one_and_update(filter, update, option).await;
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<bson::Document>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<FindOneAndUpdateOptions>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
         <std::option::Option<&'a T> as From<&'a std::option::Option<T>>>
         <std::option::Option<&'a mut T> as From<&'a mut std::option::Option<T>>>
         <std::option::Option<T> as From<T>>
         <std::option::Option<Tls> as From<TlsOptions>>
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<std::option::Option<FindOneAndUpdateOptions>>` for `bson::Document`
```

I don't know what could be wrong or what I need to implement.

Comment: your "option" part should be of type `FindOneAndUpdateOptions` no?

Comment: @mfirry I think so, because it doesn't allow to use `upsert` on option.

Comment: what version of the mongodb crate are you using?

Comment: @mfirry I am using version 1.2.0 of crate mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the declaration of `option(s)` to use the `builder`.
Something along these lines:

```
    let options = FindOneAndUpdateOptions::builder()
        .upsert(Some(true))
        .build();
```

And then pass it as `.find_one_and_update(filter, update, Some(options))`

Comment: What's `update`?

Comment: in the OP you can find let update = doc! { "$inc": { "id": 1 } };